# removing stderr from windows command

Tags: windows, batch-file, stderr

`2>&1` will take stderr and output it to stdout.

`2>filename.txt` will take stderr and dump it in filename.txt

How do I just remove it all together? Like maybe to some sort of `/dev/null` equiv?

Thanks!

Comment: Use `2>nul` to redirect stderr to the nul device

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Windows, you accomplish this via the `nul` device.

`2>nul`

Comment: Awesome - thanks! I tried null and that just created a file named null lol. But nul (without the two l's) doesn't!